# UIDocumentInteractionController, No File Extension but UTI

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uti

How do I send a file to a different App knowing which UTI the App supports? Lets say the file has no file extension, but I happen to know the UTI of the file.

I tried the following:

```
// target is a NSURL with the location of the extension less file on the system
// knownUTI is a NSString containing the UTI of the file 
    UIDocumentInteractionController* dic = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:target];  
    [dic retain];

    dic.delegate = self;
    dic.UTI = knownUTI; 
    [dic presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:superController.view animated:YES]
```

It shows the supported App, however, if I select it, it won't switch the App. The delegate calls the

```
- (void)documentInteractionController:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller willBeginSendingToApplication:(NSString *)application
```

but

```
- (void)documentInteractionController:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller didEndSendingToApplication:(NSString *)application
```

is never called and the Application is never switching.

The target App exports its UTI in the following:

```
    <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
            <array/>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>Migration DocType</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRol</key>
            <string>Shell</string>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Owner</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.mycomp.customstring</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>

...

<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.data</string>
            </array>
            <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
            <string>My custom UTI</string>
            <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.mycomp.customstring</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

As this did not work, I also tried adding a custom extension. Still, it would not work in this way. When adding the custom extension to the file I hand over to the `DocumentInteractionController` and it works. However, the list of applications shows all other applications supporting the same file extension regardless of the UTI type I supply.

Say I declare 2 UTIs in 2 different applications:

```
App1 with UTI1: com.mycomp.a  with extension .abc
App2 with UTI2: com.mycomp.b  with extension .abc
```

When handing the file to the DocumentInteractionController, and setting the UTI to `com.mycomp.a` it will also show App2 as a possible application being able to handle the file.

I defined a UTI with extension in the following manner:

```
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.data</string>
            </array>
            <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
            <string>My UTI Type</string>
            <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.mycomp.a</string>
            <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
            <dict>
                <key>public.filename-extension</key>
                <string>abc</string>
                <key>public.mime-type</key>
                <string>application/abc</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

I would really appreciate your help, I'm kind of stuck.
So, again the question: How do I send a file to an App with known UTI either without extension or having the same extension as other files of which I don't want to show the applications as choice in DocumentInteractionController?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem. However, I think it is not a very good one.

During testing I found out that when leaving the file extension away, the `UIDocumentInteractionController` will show the applications depending on the `UTI` I specified. When sending the file to the target application nothing would happen. I concluded that I need an file extension to do the final sending.

My approach was to modify the `URL` property before the file is sent to the target application and supply it the same file but with a file extension the target application accepts. Nevertheless, my application just crashed. I profiled it with Instruments and found that the problem was due to `UIDocumentInteractionController` overreleasing some proxy object.
I also saw that the final overrelease was in a method called `_invalidate` of `UIDocumentInteractionController(Private)` category was called which released the object.

As categories cannot be overridden by other categories I decided to swizzle the category method with my own implementation checking if the URL was containing a file extension or not and either redirect the call to the original `_invalidate` method or just do nothing.

The following codes shows what I did:

```
#include <objc/runtime.h>

@interface UIDocumentInteractionController(InvalidationRedirect)

-(void)_invalidateMY;
+(void)load;
void Swizzle(Class c, SEL orig, SEL newSEL);
@end

@implementation UIDocumentInteractionController(InvalidationRedirect)

void Swizzle(Class c, SEL orig, SEL newSEL)
{
    Method origMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(c, orig);
    Method newMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(c, newSEL);
    if(class_addMethod(c, orig, method_getImplementation(newMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(newMethod)))
        class_replaceMethod(c, newSEL, method_getImplementation(origMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(origMethod));
    else
        method_exchangeImplementations(origMethod, newMethod);
}

-(void)_invalidateMY{
    @synchronized(self) {
        if(![[[[self.URL lastPathComponent] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] lastObject] isEqualToString:@"extension"]) {
            [self _invalidateMY];
        }
    }
}

+(void)load
{
    Swizzle([UIDocumentInteractionController class], @selector(_invalidate), @selector(_invalidateMY));
}

@end
```

This code exchanges the original `_invalidate` method with `_invalidateMY`, resulting in every call to `_invalidate` calling `_invalidateMY` and vice versa.

The following code shows how I handle the `UIDocumentInteractionController`:

```
  // create a file without extension
  NSString *fileName = @"myFile";

  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

  NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

  NSURL* target = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory, fileName]];

  if([[@"THIS IS JUST A TEST STRING" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] writeToURL:target atomically:NO]) {
      NSLog(@"file written successfully");
  }else {
      NSLog(@"Error.. file writing failed");
  }

  UIDocumentInteractionController* dic = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:target];
  [dic retain];
  dic.delegate = self;


  // set the UTI to the known UTI we want to list applications for
  dic.UTI = @"com.mycomp.a";

  [dic presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:superController.view animated:YES];
```

And this code shows the `UIDocumentInteractionController`'s delegate method which exchanges the URL:

```
- (void)documentInteractionController:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller willBeginSendingToApplication:(NSString *)application
{
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSURL* newTarget = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.extension", controller.URL]];
    // rename file to file with extension
    if (![fileMgr moveItemAtURL:controller.URL toURL:newTarget error:&error] && error) {
        NSLog(@"Error moving file: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    @synchronized(controller) {
        //exchange URL with URL+extension
        controller.URL = newTarget; //<- this results in calling _invalidate
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:controller.URL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]);
}
```

This solution works, but in my opinion it is a dirty hack, there must be a better solution.

Comment: I found a simpler solution. The code from the `willBeginSendingToApplication:` can already be executed after the open in menu was successfully called, this erases the need to swizzle the methods!

Comment: Please provide code for this. I have tried setting the name property but it does not reflect in the 3rd party app.

Comment: Yes, a detailed writeup of the *real* solution would be most helpful.